# How to Share HTML on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

In the picture below, the mobile screen shown is an html preview portion.I want to share the html showing the preview mobile to facebook. How can i post html to facebook(PHP/JQUERY)

Pls see the screen view [image: Screen view]

Any help will be appeciated

Comment: Hmmm... I have read this several times and I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Could you give us more context?

Comment: @BenD The page shown is an offer adding page in webapp.The offer added here will be displayed in a mobile application.The mobile shown in picture will display how the offer will looks in mobile. v hav a fb share/post button in this page to share the mobile screen preview to facebook.

Answer (score 2):

**NO, you cant post HTML code to Facebook.
check link below, to see what we can post on facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by facebook javascript Sdk.

here i give sample

`javascript`:

```
function share(){
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Put name',
    link: 'put link',
    picture: 'image url',
    description: 'descrition'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response) {
       alert ('success');
    } else {
       alert ('Failed');
    }
  }
);  
}
```

in `html`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="share()" >Click to share</a>
```

Comment: Can v add html content to description?

Comment: i am not sure but u can give a try. may be not, i have tried to put html when uploading image on facebook. but seems they filter html tag

Comment: so nothing to do at all. But surprised why -1 of this answer and dont know who gave it? where is the wrong of this answer?